# when i make a $group how can i return the total sum of a property present in all objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "provider": "provider 1",
    "debts": [
      {
        "debt": 500,
        "paid": true
      },
      {
        "debt": 900,
        "paid": false
      },
      {
        "debt": 600,
        "paid": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "provider": "provider 2",
    "debts": [
      {
        "debt": 500,
        "paid": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want each object to store in the `total` field the sum of the `debt` field contained in the `debts`  array (`debts.debt`) ONLY if the`paid`property is false. (in my real code it works well up to here).

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 [
  {
    $unwind: "$debts",
  },
      {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",

      total: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: ["$debts.paid", false] }, "debts.debt", 0],
        },
      },
    },
  }
]
```

how can I get the total of the sum of the `total` property contained in all my objects that met the above condition?

```
{
  "debts_providers": [
    {
      "_id": "5f29af0a17196c1624f7dd88",
      "total": 1500
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f29af0a17196c1624f7dd89",
      "total": 500
    }
  ],
  "sum_total_objects": 2000  /*900+600+500*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right track, just need to replace root with `debt_providers`,

- you missed `$` in first group `$cond` `then` part, it should be `$debts.debt`
- second `$group` that is required,

  - create new field `debt_providers` and push `$$ROOT` because documents are unwind in independent but we need to set together in `debt_providers`
  - create new field `sum_total_objects` to `$sum` all total value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$debts"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$debts.paid", false] }, 
            "$debts.debt", // corrected debts.debt to $debts.debt
            0
          ] 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // added here
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      debt_providers: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      sum_total_objects: { $sum: "$total" }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/esRanLrIB2o

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `$unwind`- it's better to process an array using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to sum up only unpaid `debts`. Then you need to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get a total value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            total: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$debts",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [ "$$value", { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.paid", false] }, "$$this.debt", 0] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            debt_providers: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            sum_total_objects: { $sum: "$total" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MSuqn7K7cwx)